# Points of Differentiability

Tags: analysis

At which points is the function $f:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ defined by $f(x,y)=|x||y||$ differentiable?

ok so for x and/or y not equal to 0, I worked out the partial derivatives which are continuous (didn't give a proof of this), hence I claim it is differentiable in this region (so the entire $\mathbb R^2$ plane minus the x and y axis)

however, on the axis it seems clearly it isnt differentiable, but for some odd reason im not getting a convincing proof, i know a vector mapping to its norm isnt differentiable at 0 but here a single component instead is being mapped to its norm and then multiplied by the other component, so I'm sure I can't use that result.

Any help will be appreciated ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a function is differentiable, then it must be differentiable when restricted to any straight line.

The function $x\mapsto |x|$ is not differentiable at zero, hence the function $x \mapsto |x||y|$ is not differentiable at $x=0$ whenever $y \neq 0$. A similar situation, mutatis mutandis, applies for $y \mapsto |x||y|$.

However, $f$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$. $|f((x,y)) - 0 - 0 (x,y)^T| = |x||y| \le \|(x,y)\|^2$, hence $f$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$ with derivative $(0,0)$.

Comment: ok my only query is the last part, how did you get the 0 for the linear function/derivative in the modulus, from the partial derivatives? but aren't they undefined?

Comment: Are you referring to differentiability at $(0,0)$? Well, from other problems, I know that if the function has the form $|f(x)| \le K \|x\|^2$, then it is differentiable at $x=0$ and the derivative is zero (cf. the single variable function $x \mapsto x^2$).

Answer (score 1):

$$f_x(x_0,y) = \lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}\frac{ f(x+dx,y) - f(x,y) }{x+dx-x}$$

$$f_x(x_0,y) = \lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}\frac{ |x+dx||y| - |x||y| }{dx}$$

$$f_x(x_0,y) = \lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}\frac{ |y|(|x+dx| - |x|) }{dx}$$ $y \ne 0$

We see when $x_0 = 0$ the $LHL = -1 $ and $RHL = 1$ . Therefore it is not differentiable at $x =0$ for all $y \ne 0$ . Similar argument goes for $y$ and hence it is not differentiable on the axes

However $f$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$ . Check that by definition of partial derivative .

Comment: sorry but I dont get what you mean by LHL, RHL and if I presume thats equivalent to LHS, RHS then I dont see how the value of -1,1 comes out

Comment: LHL means evaluating the limit from left hand side ie $x\rightarrow0^-$ . RHL means evaluating the limit from right hand side ie $x\rightarrow0^+$